# How can you get char values from non ascii character

Tags: python, c++, ascii, ctypes

Hello so I have a string in python type `POINTER(wintypes.BYTE)` I am using [DATA_BLOB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa381414(v=vs.85)) in python(

```
class CREATE_DATA_BLOB(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('cbData', wintypes.DWORD), ('pbData', POINTER(wintypes.BYTE))]
```

) I have a DLL that encrypts the data. after it encrypts the data, the data is saved inside the `pbData` of the data_blob structure. The problem is the values inside the `pbData`(`pbData[0]`) for example has `-42` in it, another example is that some of them are between 0 to 255 - they are good but some are completely random numbers and I can't figure out how to turn these non-ASCII number to a character. In c++ I use [writeFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile) function and I just send `pbData` and everything works great in python is not the case I have this error if I am trying to write `pbData` to a text file:

```
file.write(data_out.pbData)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not LP_c_byte
```

I really don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: I think `wintypes.BYTE` is a `signed char` or `char` (which is usually signed too). Do you really get `wintypes.BYTE` values between 128 and 255?

Comment: No, I get -42 -39 -100 in some of the values for some reason super weird I can't figure out a way to solve it the weird thing is that in c++ the values are good in python the values are not(values of pbData[i]) @TedLyngmo

Comment: In Windows, a `BYTE` is `unsigned` (0-255). A `wintypes.BYTE` is signed (128-127). If the `wintypes.BYTE` is negative you could just add 256 to it to get the same value as you'd have in C++ (on a 2's complement machine).

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's what I just thought about but why in C++ it does that automatically

Comment: It uses the types you want. In Windows (C++) a `BYTE` is defined as `unsigned char`. Unfortunately, `wintypes.BYTE` does not map to the correct type for the task (since it's singed for some reason). When looking in `ctypes/wintypes.py` I see that there's a `UCHAR` type - but it has been commented out. Otherwise, I would have tried using that instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you so much

Comment: @TedLyngmo but still when I did the +256 it didn't work the decryption of the file had problems

Comment: Well, after you did +256 you should have values between 0 and 255 (inclusive). If that's not enough, you have other problems that might be solved by writing the file in binary mode (see @CristiFati's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

There are several problems:

- `wintypes.BYTE` is signed ([[Python.Bugs]: wrong type for wintypes.BYTE](https://bugs.python.org/issue16376))
- `file.write` works with *Python* strings (in your case) not *ctypes* pointers (and there's no implicit conversion between them)
- Going further (this would appear after solving the other 2): you have "special" *char*s in your buffer. That means that you shouldn't treat is as a "normal string", but as a binary sequence (otherwise you may get encode / decode errors). As a consequence, open the file where you want to dump its contents to, in **binary mode** (e.g.: `file = open(file_name, "wb")`).

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes as ct
> >>> from ctypes import wintypes as wt
> >>>
> >>> class CREATE_DATA_BLOB(ct.Structure):
> ...     _fields_ = [
> ...             ("cbData", wt.DWORD),
> ...             ("pbData", ct.POINTER(ct.c_ubyte)),  # wt.BYTE is signed !!!
> ...     ]
> ...
> >>>
> >>> buf_initial = b"AB\xD6CD\xD9EF\x9CGH"  # Contains the 3 chars you mentioned
> >>> buf_initial
> b'AB\xd6CD\xd9EF\x9cGH'
> >>> # Populate the structure as it was done from C++
> ...
> >>> blob = CREATE_DATA_BLOB(len(buf_initial), ct.cast(ct.create_string_buffer(buf_initial), ct.POINTER(ct.c_ubyte)))
> >>> blob.cbData, blob.pbData
> (11, <__main__.LP_c_ubyte object at 0x00000154FF6998C8>)
> >>>
> >>> buf_final = bytes(blob.pbData[:blob.cbData])  # Convert the pointer explicitly to Python bytes
> >>> buf_final
> b'AB\xd6CD\xd9EF\x9cGH'
> >>> buf_initial == buf_final
> True
> >>>
> >>> with open("q058436070_out.bin", "wb") as file:
> ...     file.write(buf_final)
> ...
> 11
> ```

Comment: What about when I want to decrypt the data should I read it as byte to? and how the text file would look and what about the regular characters they have to be binary to right?

Comment: You should **definitely** read it as bytes. If you read it as text, you should convert it to bytes afterwards, and you will get errors there. Note that (simplified) a *Python **3*** string maps to a `wchar_t*` on *Win*.

Comment: The number of bytes written to file (which is the same as `blob.cbData` displayed a few lines above).

Comment: But how do I print the encrypted data to the text file?

Comment: What do you mean "*print to text file*"? The last lines write the encrypted data into a file. But binary data and text files don't quite match.

Comment: You are a legend

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing (as you didn't show the code), but you're doing it wrong. If you copy paste from the snippet in the answer, it should work (as it did in my case). :)

Comment: No, I didn't it all works I am not that stupid "Copy and paste" haha the encryption works at least the decryption doesn't for some reason can you help me with that?

Comment: I don't know how the encryption or the decryption are implemented (as I didn't see the code), only the intermediate *Python* part. But if you post another question explaining what doesn't work, I'll try.

Comment: a quick question - if I don't write it as wb it would write like 5 char(something like that) to the text file, right?

Comment: You can't not writing it with "wb", or if you do a conversion will take place leading to unpredictable results. You should get the text file out of your mind.

Comment: As  I said earlier: **don't!** It will generate *Undefined Behavior* depending on the contents. As a matter of fact you can try, to see the results. But do not rely on it to work every time.

Comment: forget what I said it works great I fixed my error by the way thanks again